# Linknode R4 error: espcomm_upload_mem failed

Tags: arduino-esp8266

I am very new to this sort of thing so any help would be appreciated. I've spent 2 days trying to correct the errors I'm getting but I am still having no luck. I am following this tutorial here http://www.themakersworkbench.com/tutorial/how-use-amazon-alexa-control-linknode-r4-esp8266-4-channel-relay-board. I am using the same cables he linked in the tutorial (://amzn.to/2h7PdEz) (usb to uart cable) (://amzn.to/2h7RDDf) (5v 2a power supply). I gathered the code from the link provided and updated it with the relevant information for it to connect to my wifi, other than that I made no changes to the code. (they wont let me put links in as this is my first post just add http to the front of the links)

The problem I am having is when I try to upload my code to the board its not working, the code compiles fine then encounters the error listed below. I'm sure this is something simple and I've scoured everywhere ensuring proper settings but im still unable to upload the code. I even tried the serial monitor at 115200 entering "AT" and getting the output `UC. Just to cover some of the basics i connected the tx to the rx on the board and the rx to the tx on the board, and ground to ground. The power is on and I can see the power led indicator lit, this is plugged directly into the wall. I downloaded 1.8.3 arduino ide and installed the ESP8266 board manager and I am using the generic version flash mode QIO at 115200 baud rate.

Thanks for taking the time to look at this and again I'm very new so please direct me in the right direction if this question has already been answered (I searched myself ALOT).

---

```
Arduino: 1.8.3 (Windows 10), Board: "Generic ESP8266 Module, 80 MHz, 40MHz, QIO, 115200, 512K (64K SPIFFS), ck, Disabled, None"

Build options changed, rebuilding all
Archiving built core (caching) in: C:\Users\Bro2D2\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_585316\core\core_esp8266_esp8266_generic_CpuFrequency_80,FlashFreq_40,FlashMode_qio,UploadSpeed_115200,FlashSize_512K64,ResetMethod_ck,Debug_Disabled,DebugLevel_None_____f179b2dc0cd843b50353b7c87d0452e9.a
Sketch uses 250081 bytes (57%) of program storage space. Maximum is 434160 bytes.
Global variables use 37816 bytes (46%) of dynamic memory, leaving 44104 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
C:\Users\Bro2D2\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\esptool\0.4.9/esptool.exe -vv -cd ck -cb 115200 -cp COM3 -ca 0x00000 -cf C:\Users\Bro2D2\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_953054/wemos.ino.bin 
esptool v0.4.9 - (c) 2014 Ch. Klippel <ck@atelier-klippel.de>
    setting board to ck
    setting baudrate from 115200 to 115200
    setting port from COM1 to COM3
    setting address from 0x00000000 to 0x00000000
    espcomm_upload_file
    espcomm_upload_mem
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
opening bootloader
resetting board
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: E0 instead of C0
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: E0 instead of C0
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: E0 instead of C0
resetting board
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: E0 instead of C0
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: E0 instead of C0
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: E0 instead of C0
resetting board
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: E0 instead of C0
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: E0 instead of C0
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: E0 instead of C0
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix your specific problem, but I was running into the same error and ultimately it was the drivers for my usb cord. I believe the drivers for your cord can be [found here](http://www.ftdichip.com/FTDrivers.htm).